# problems with malloc using .C() in R

Tags: c, r

My problem is a bit undefined. I have a program in C that works fine when I call it with .C() in R, but since I'm dealing with big matrices like 30000x20000 it was getting a stack overflow. Now I have the same program but more efficeintly coded using malloc, and it works perfectlry in C, compiles well with R CMD SHLIB but when I call it with .C() my pc basicly stops working independantly of the size of the matrices involved.

The C code is the following (sorry it is a bit long):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#ifdef NAN
/* NAN is supported */
#endif
#ifdef INFINITY
/* INFINITY is supported */
#endif

void dnk_c(double *sortedFsample, unsigned long int n, unsigned long int k, double *dKol){

  double min(double a, double b) {
    return (a < b) ? a : b;
  }

  double max(double a, double b) {
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
  }

  double r_abs(double a){
    return (a < 0) ? -a : a;
  }

  int cmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return (*(double*)a - *(double*)b);
  }

  double superior(double x, double i, double m){
    double op1 = r_abs(x-(i)/(m));
    double op2 = r_abs(x-(i-1)/(m));
    return max(op1,op2);
  }

  double termino1, termino2, f, g, t, h1, h2, l=1.0, m=n-k;
  unsigned long int i, j, filas;

  double **matrixA, **matrixB;

  matrixA = (double **) malloc((k+1)*sizeof(double *));
  matrixB = (double **) malloc((k+1)*sizeof(double *));

  for (i=0; i <= k; i++) {
    matrixA[i] = (double *) malloc(n*sizeof(double));
    matrixB[i] = (double *) malloc(n*sizeof(double));

    for (j=0; j < n; j++) {
      matrixA[i][j] = 0;
      matrixB[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }

  for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    j  = k;
    f  = i-m+1;
    l  = 0;
    h2 = min(i,j);
    h1 = max(l,f);

    for(; h1 <= h2; h1++) {
      t = i-h1+1;
      filas = (unsigned long int) h1;
      matrixA[filas][i] = superior(sortedFsample[i], t, m);
    }
  }

  for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    j  = n-m-1;
    f  = i-m;
    g  = 0;
    h2 = min(i,j);
    h1 = max(g,f);

    for(; h1 <= h2; h1++) {
      t = i-h1+1;
      filas = (unsigned long int) h1;
      matrixB[filas][i] = r_abs(sortedFsample[i] - (i-h1)/m);
    }
  }


  i = 1;
  j = n-m;

  for(; i< n; i++) {
    f  = i-m+1;
    g  = 1;
    h2 = min(i,j);
    h1 = max(g,f);

    matrixA[0][i] = max(matrixA[0][i], matrixA[0][i-1]);

    for(; h1 <= h2; h1++) {
      filas = (unsigned long int) h1;
      termino1 = max(matrixA[filas][i], matrixA[filas][i-1]);
      termino2 = max(matrixA[filas][i], matrixB[filas-1][i-1]);

      matrixA[filas][i] = min(termino1, termino2);
    }

    t  = n-m-1;
    f  = i-m;
    g  = 0;
    h2 = min(i,t);
    h1 = max(g,f);

    filas = (unsigned long int) h1;
    matrixB[0][i] = max(matrixB[0][i], matrixA[0][i-1]);

    for(; h1 <= h2; h1++) {
      filas = (unsigned long int) h1;
      termino1 = max(matrixB[filas][i], matrixA[filas][i-1]);

      if (filas == 0) {
        termino2 = max(matrixB[filas][i], - INFINITY);
      }
      else{
        termino2 = max(matrixB[filas][i], matrixB[filas-1][i-1]);
      }
      matrixB[filas][i] = min(termino1, termino2);
    }
  }

  filas = (unsigned long int) t;
  unsigned long int n_int = (unsigned long int) (n-1);
  double result = min(matrixA[filas+1][n_int], matrixB[filas][n_int]);

  for (i=0; i <= k; i++) {
    free(matrixA[i]);
    free(matrixB[i]);
  }

  free(matrixA);
  free(matrixB);

  dKol[0] = result;
}
```

The R CMD SHLIB returns:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c /home/hristo/pCloudDrive/R/dnk_c.c -o /home/hristo/pCloudDrive/R/dnk_c.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o /home/hristo/pCloudDrive/R/dnk_c.so /home/hristo/pCloudDrive/R/dnk_c.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
```

My call in R to the function is:

```
dyn.load("dnk_c.so")
.C("dnk_c", as.double(sortedFsample), as.integer(N), as.integer(k), as.double(dKol))
```

I don't see what am I doing wrong, and there is no error message. Can somebady give me a hint of what could be happening?
Many thanks!!!

Comment: I guess, by the way you call "dnk_c" in `.C`, its definition should be `(double *sortedFsample, int *n, int *k, double *dKol)` as R passes pointers from its objects to the C function and dereference "n" and "k" in your code.

Comment: Indeed, you were right!!!! Thanks a lot!!! Such a silly mistake :)